# Swift 3 - Missing argument label '...' in call

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am building a basic to-do list.

I made a Swift file that intends to add items to a list

```
import UIKit

class AddKey: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var keyValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var keyDescription: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "dismissAndSaveKey" {
            let key = Key(description: keyDescription.text!)
            KeyStore.sharedInstance.add(key) // I get an ERROR at this line
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> KeyStore.sharedInstance.add(key)", I get a "Missing argument label
>   'key:' in call

Now, KeyStore has a member

`var keys: [Key] = []`

And sharedInstance creates a static instance of the class

Moreover, the add method is defined

```
func add(key: Key) {
    keys.append(key)
}
```

Why would I have to specify the type of key in order to pass key to the add method? Moreover, if I do specify the type of key, the compiler complains that it expected type Key and not Key.type.

If I write

```
KeyStore.sharedInstance.add(key)
```

as

```
KeyStore.sharedInstance.keys.append(key)
```

the error is gone and everything works.

Comment: Argument labels are mandatory in Swift 3. You can add `_` in front of the label if you want to be able to ignore it.

Comment: `func add(_ key: Key) {`